# Android How to save the state of checkboxes that are 3 different checked states

Tags: android, checkbox, savestate

I am new to Android development, and I am wondering how to save a checkbox state locally for when the user reopens the app, and the checkbox stays either red, yellow, or green. I have my code in a fragment, and every time I open the app, it is the default red that I had set. I have custom checkboxes where I have them circular, and when the user clicks on the checkbox it stays checked, but changes the colors. I have researched a lot, and I have tried SharedPreferences, but it's not working, and I need to know what the logic is for having the user click the checkbox and to see if it is red, yellow, or green. What I have seen is for a checkbox just being checked once, and that it is saves the state if it is checked or not, but I have checkboxes that are being checked multiple times and changing colors every time. Here is my code for the method I use for the checkboxes:

```
public int checked(CheckBox checkBox, int count){
    if (checkBox.isChecked()){
        count++;
    } else if (!checkBox.isChecked()){
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
        count++;
    }
    if (count == 1){
        checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_yellow_checkbox);
    }
    if (count == 2){
        checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_green_checkbox);
    }
    if (count > 2){
        count = 0;
        checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_red_checkbox);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Here is the checkbox method itself when it is checked.

```
chkStart.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            countStart = checked(chkStart, countStart);
        }
    });
```

So, I am wondering if there is a way to save the checkbox state inside of the checked method or to have other methods to make this happen. If anyone has the knowledge of having the state saved for the checkboxes and to have them stay a certain drawable with it being checked 0, 1 or 2 times, I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, SharedPreferences would be a good choice to persist the state of the CheckBoxes even if app is closed. Just save the correct key:value duple to make it works: I would use the checkboxId as key and the count variable you are using as value. For example:

```
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("preferences_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();

    chkStart.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            countStart = checked(chkStart, countStart);
            editor.putInt("checkStartId", countStart);
            editor.apply();
        }
    });
}

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        int value = mSharedPreferences.getInt("checkStartId", 0) // 0 is the default value, in case there is not value saved
    }
```

To set the state of the CheckBox when the app starts (for example on method `onResume()`) get the count value from `SharedPreferences` for the specific checkBox and set the correct color.

Comment: Can you show me how to get the count value in the onResume()? Is it editor.getInt(something) or what is the method to get the count value. Thanks!

Comment: I also get a null pointer exception with the context variable. What do I initialize context to be so that I don't have a null pointer exception?

Comment: I've updated my answer, I haven't test it but I think it'll work, use it as an example! :)

Comment: Do you use the variable value? If so, how would I find out what the color of the checkbox is?

Comment: Is there a way to just do this in a fragment, or do I have to have an activity to use sharedpreferences? I'd rather not have an activity because the whole set up I have is with fragments, but if I have to then I will, but hopefully I can just do it in a fragment. Please let me know if I can do it in just a fragment.

Comment: Of course you can use it on a fragment. About the color thing, just use the code you posted: if value is 1, set yellow color, if value is 2 green and greater than 2 red.

Comment: It seems to not be working. I'm not sure if it is actually getting the values of the checkboxes and having them stay the color they were last checked. It keeps being red when I come back to it even when not closing the app and just going to a different part of the app. Are you sure that this code can work in just a fragment and no activity? Can you actually save data in a fragment?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just take care with lifecycle (onCreate, onResume, etc): fragment lifecycle is different from activity lifecycle. Try to use debugger and logger (log.i, log.e, log.w, etc) to check if values are saved/restored correctly.